# Opening HDF5 satellite images in GDAL with Python?

Tags: python, gdal, hdf5

I want to read and open HDF5 satellite images by python for batch processing.

How can I read and open both image bands and meta data?

For batch processing I need to geo-reference and read IR bands. Then clip them and calculate Brightness temperature for IR bands based on some formulas.

Comment: Do you want to do it in ArcPy or pure python?

Comment: It is not important since I work with python 2.7 which is applied in Arcmap 10.2 I need to read the images for batch processing.

Comment: Since you have ArcMap it is easier to do this in Arcpy rather that python libraries such as [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/)

Comment: you can simply open [hdf5(*.h5) data](https://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/files/exbyapi/h5ex_d_alloc.h5) with Arcmap. Simply drag and drop the hdf5 file to the map and it show the data. For the batch processing you should declare what type of batch processing you need to do?

Comment: For batch processing I need to read IR bands then geo-reference them and then clip them and then calculate Brightness temperature for IR bands based on some formulas.

Comment: What is the source of your hdf5? hdf5 files usually have an associated meta data that contains the geo-referencing information. ArcGIS automatically reconize these hdf as a raster product. So sometimes there is no need for geo-referencing .

Comment: I draged the these HDF5 images in Arc map but it could not read metadata completely and give the message that the data does not have spatial projection. Then I checked these data in QGIS again I had the same problem. The HDF5 images belong to INSAT-3D images (Indian meteorological satellite) .

Comment: Please don't respond to requests for more information in comments,  *edit* your question instead.

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved in Python by leveraging the [GDAL Python bindings](http://gdal.org/python/), as HDF5 is a GDAL supported format.

```
from osgeo import gdal

hdf_ds = gdal.Open("/path/to/hdf/hdf_file.hdf", gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

# replace <subdataset> with the number of the subdataset you need, starting with 0
band_ds = gdal.Open(hdf_ds.GetSubDatasets()[<subdataset>][0], gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

band_array = band_ds.ReadAsArray()
```

`band_array` will then be a numpy array with the values of your subdataset.

You can find out which subdataset to address either by using the `.GetSubDatasets()` method or by using `gdalinfo` from the command line.